# Customizing, branding and styling the look & feel of InfoPath 2007 forms?

Tags: css, sharepoint, forms, infopath, branding

StackOverflow'ers,

I was wondering what the available techniques/tools/best practices are there for creating custom branded InfoPath 2007 forms to be used within MOSS.  I realize this question is fairly broad, but any direction is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is a very thorough and entertaining 7-part [walkthrough of how to create a leave form](http://sharepointmagazine.net/technical/customisation/a-tribute-to-the-humble-leave-form) on SharePoint Magazine.

It doesn't call out best practices as such, however it does show the full process from taking business requirements and taking them to a final solution within the product.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of the few people in my company who like infopath  forms. But it is limited how useful these can be.

for branding use Microsoft Office InfoPath 2007.

best practices for deploying are to always package  as wsp and install that way.